# maven зависимости

Tags: maven, зависимости

например есть модуль parent , у коготорого есть

```
<module>
1
</module>
и 
<module>
2
</module>
```

если module 1 подключает какую-нибудь библиотеку например jackson , а модуль 2 , подключает модуль 1 . будет ли эта библиотека доступна в модуле 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если 1 модуль подключает 2 модуль, то все зависимости 2 модуля будут доступны в 1 модуле. Это называется Transitive Dependencies (Зависимости зависимостей).